# decoupling Array stores

Tags: arrays, extjs

I found that ExtJS's Array stores are so tightly binded that if i want to keep the original in some temp store, it is also modified. i.e. if i do something like this:

Ext.data.ArrayStores A, temp

A = {something}

temp = A

Itemselector: store = A

A.remove(some records)

I find that Itemselector: store is automatically modified with A, that is what i want but temp is also modified as A is modified. How can i break this sync between temp and A?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not ExtJS Array store that is tightly bond, It's the Javascript! If you search you will find similar issues with other frameworks as well. And there are enough discussions on stackoverflow itself.

Now, here is your solution by an example:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore',{
    fields: [
       {name: 'fname',type: 'string'},
       {name: 'age', type: 'int'}       
    ],
    data: [
        ['Sammy',28],
        ['Steve', 31],
        ['Albert', 30],
        ['Abdel', 28],
        ['Godwin',28]
    ]
});

var data = [];
var dupStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        fields: [
           {name: 'fname',type: 'string'},
           {name: 'age', type: 'int'}       
        ]
});

// Copy all records to a new array...
myStore.each(function (rec){
    data.push (rec.copy());
});    

dupStore.loadRecords(data); // Your duplicate store
```

Note how we create a copy of records from myStore. A simple assign like `data = myStore.data` will not create a new array!

The other way is to create a object using the `clone()`. But as far as I know, this is also a shallow copy and hence will not work.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guess what you want is to create one store and keep a back up copy of it in its original state? If so you could just create the store then keep a backup of just its data more of a cache of it.

```
Ext.data.ArrayStores A;
//fill a with records
var cacheOfAData = A.data;//Takes all the data in the store and caches it.
A.remove(someRecords);//Remove records the cacheOfAData should still remain with the original data
```

This is just one way of doing this, there are many more ways.